# SQLiteDatabase.insert() and SQLiteDatabase.execSQL("insert into ...") doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm working on an Android application in Java. In my application I need, among other things, to store an address in a database. My address is stored in a table named "adresse". This table is defined as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "adresse" (
    "numero_rue"  TEXT,
    "type_voie"   TEXT,
    "voie"        TEXT,
    "code_postal" TEXT,
    "ville"       TEXT
);
```

I've tried to insert an address in my table by two different methods:

```java
public void setAdresse(String numRue, String typeVoie, String voie, String codePostal, String ville) {
    // First one
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("numero_rue" , numRue    );
    values.put("type_voie"  , typeVoie  );
    values.put("voie"       , voie      );
    values.put("code_postal", codePostal);
    values.put("ville"      , ville     );

    db.insert("adresse", null, values);

    // Second one
    String req = "insert into adresse (numero_rue, type_voie, voie, code_postal, ville) values";
    req += "(\"" + numRue + "\",\"" + typeVoie + "\",\"" + voie + "\",\"" + codePostal + "\",\"" + ville + "\")";

    db.execSQL(req);
}
```

I call the `setAdresse(...)` method in this method:

```java
public void valider(View paramView) {
    [ data recovery without problems ]

    final DatabaseAccess db = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    db.open();

    db.setAdresse(numRue, typeVoie, voie, codePostal, ville);

    db.close();
}
```

I show you my constructor, my `open()`, `close()` and `getInstance()` methods:

```java
private DatabaseAccess(Context context) { this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context); }

public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if( instance == null ) instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);

    return instance;
}

public void open() { this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase(); }

public void close() { if( this.db != null ) this.db.close(); }
```

My problem is that inserting the data into the table is not working. I don't find errors in the logs and my application does not crash. I don't think it is a code error and someone told me it could be linked to my "driver utilisation".

Comment: Check the return value of `db.insert("adresse", null, values);`. If it is not -1 then the insertion succeeded.

Comment: "72". Looks like there's no problem here

Comment: This means that the row is inserted without problem.

Comment: Yes. Is it supposed to inform me of this success in the logs ? ( if yes, i don't have it )

Comment: You can check in your code about the insertion: `if (db.insert("adresse", null, values)) == -1 {...} else {...}`

Comment: "My problem is that inserting the data into the table is not working" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I verified the data i wanted to insert and the return value of my insertion. I don't see what it can be if it's not this. If you have another idea, I'm listening carefully

Comment: @forpas We already verified it. I still have tried what you said and it confirm what we saw

Comment: The data that you want insert are inserted fine with your code. I don't understand what th eproblem is.

Comment: "I verified the data i wanted to insert" -- I do not know what that means. You might consider looking in the database to see if the data is there.

Comment: @CommonsWare By "I verified the data i wanted to insert" i meant that i verified the ContentValues instance content before trying to insert it. I have a visual studio code extension to see all the database data and my "adresse" table is empty. I also already have a function in my code to get the data in my table and it never gave me something different that `null`

Comment: @forpas maybe the problem could come from the library version i use ? In my build.gradle file, i have this line with other implementations : `implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'`. I already tried to replace the "2.0.1" by a "+" and there are no difference

Comment: As I said your code works fine if insert() returns a value different than -1. If you can't see the data in the table this means that either the tool you are using to see the data does not work or the database that you inspect is not the database that your code creates in the device/emulator.

Comment: *someone told me it could be linked to my "driver utilisation"* - that's not a thing.

Answer (score 0):

can you check this [link](https://github.com/PM1509/SqliteSample). It is a github sample project for inserting in sqlite table